# Java compilation in eclim

Tags: vim, eclim

According to [passing JVM args](http://groups.google.com/group/eclim-user/browse_thread/thread/d6f9442524b9d670) there is no support yet in eclim for passing arguments to the JVM when running Java from eclim by `:Java`. I assume the same is true for java compilation with `:Javac`. Is there some hack that will allow me not to pass arguments to the compiler but then at least have `:Javac` do eg. `javac -Xlint:unchecked` even though it's to be a permanent change ? Another usecase would be to compile with a different compiler.

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like](http://eclim.org/vim/java/java.html) you can now set jvm flags with `org.eclim.java.run.jvmargs` and javac flags with `org.eclim.java.compile.args`.

(See also the [Eclim Settings doc](http://eclim.org/vim/settings.html).)